# How to charge all gas fee to a General Master Wallet

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ether, tokens

We are currently developing a blockchain platform that deals with sending of tokens from users to users, and as you know, ETH is required as a gas fee to be paid for any ERC20 token transfer from a Wallet.

But we don't want our users to pay this gas fee when sending tokens to each others, instead we want all these gas fee to be charged to a general '**Master Wallet**’.

Our team has been having problems in developing a **master wallet** that pays gas charges for all child-wallet under it. Is this something anyone can help us with?

We would appreciate any help we get.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pay gas on behalf of another address, yet. The ability for either party to pay gas is a planned upgrade in the future, as seen in [this post](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/bd136e662fca4154787b44cded8d2a29b993be66/EIPS/abstraction.md) by Vitalik.

If you are using ERC20 tokens, there is an option being worked on that allows you to pay transfers in tokens instead of gas, in one transaction. This is [ERC865](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/865), and may be applicable in your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply Gonzalo. Will pass this on to our team.